# Change Crystal Reports 8.5 connection to SQL Server 2005 dynamically in VB6

Tags: sql-server-2005, vb6, crystal-reports-8.5

We need to connect some Crystal Reports 8.5 to a SQL Server database under MS Windows 7, 64 bit. The query are not handled by the VB6 code of our application, but is included in the Reports and by the time, we would like to avoid passing to the Reports data extracted from the code, because we should modify all the Reports deeply.
Since the application will be installed on different locations, where the connection data will vary, we need to change this information at runtime, by vb6 code, so that the reports point to the appropriate data.
This is the test code we use:

```
    Dim nTables As Integer
    Dim iCount As Integer
    Dim iRitCW As Integer


    '-----> Ritorno msgBox
    Dim RitMsg As Integer
    Dim sRitCW As String * 255

    jobnum = 0

    If PEOpenEngine() = False Then
        MsgBox "Errore Engine"
    End If

    jobnum = PEOpenPrintJob("c:\test\report1.rpt")

'Declarations
Dim logonInfo As PELogOnInfo

logonInfo.StructSize = PE_SIZEOF_LOGON_INFO
logonInfo.ServerName = "dellone\sqlexpress2005" + Chr(0)
logonInfo.DatabaseName = "TEST" + Chr(0)
logonInfo.UserID = "sa" + Chr(0)
logonInfo.Password = "sasasa_2005" + Chr(0)

If (PELogOnServer("p2smon.dll", logonInfo) = False) Then
        MsgBox "Connessione fallita", vbExclamation, NomeApplicazione
        iRitCW = PEGetErrorCode(jobnum)
        RitMsg = MsgBox("Errore n. : " + Str(iRitCW), vbExclamation, NomeApplicazione)
        End
End If

nTables = PEGetNTables(jobnum)

For iCount = 0 To nTables - 1
    If PESetNthTableLogOnInfo(jobnum, iCount, logonInfo, True) = False Then
        MsgBox "Errore : PESetNthTableLogOn", vbExclamation, NomeApplicazione
Screen.MousePointer = 0
        Exit Sub
    End If
   If (PETestNthTableConnectivity(jobnum, iCount) = False) Then
      MsgBox ("Errore nella connessione per la tabella:" & iCount)
   End If
Next iCount



      If PEOutputToPrinter(jobnum, 1) = False Then
MsgBox "Stampa del documento fallita", vbExclamation, NomeApplicazione
Screen.MousePointer = 0
Exit Sub
End If

    If PEStartPrintJob(jobnum, True) = False Then
        MsgBox "Stampa in anteprima fallita", vbExclamation, NomeApplicazione
        iRitCW = PEGetErrorCode(jobnum)
        RitMsg = MsgBox("Errore di stampa n. : " + Str(iRitCW), vbExclamation, NomeApplicazione)
        Exit Sub
    End If
Screen.MousePointer = 0
```

Normally the error that is reported is 536 on PELogonServer and is 599 after PEStartPrintJob.
We therefore ask whethere the data wich wich we use to initialize the logoninfo data structure are sintactically correct. If the ServerName string has to be escaped in some particular way. We ask confirmation about the dll we use (“p2smon.dll”) in PELogOnServer function, whereas we tried without success with “p2ssql.dll” and any further explanation that may help us to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the CR8.5 viewer in VB6? Because this code says nothing to me. When i show a report i start with declaring the Crystal Reports application and report.
  Dim crApp As CRAXDRT.Application
  Dim crRep As CRAXDRT.Report